# CSS for Table Properties in HTML

Tags: html, css, html-table

In a single page am having multiple tables but only for a set of tables want to apply css not for all. which for `table bgcolor`, `th color`, `border color` and `text color`.So I tried to create a separate class `.mytable` and applied which is not working but if I make that **`.mytable`** to **`table`** it comes for all the tables.Please help me to solve this.Thanks in Advance.

[jsFiddle Link is Here](http://jsfiddle.net/joekingleo/y8B2j/)

```
<style>
.mytable td th   //instead of .mytable table it works
{
    border:1px solid green;
}
th{
    background-color:green;
    color:white;
}
</style>



<table class="mytable">
<tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Peter</td>
    <td>Griffin</td>
    <td>$100</td>
</tr>

</table>
<table> /// no need of this css
</table>
```

Comment: It's working. Try with this one http://jsfiddle.net/8td9n/

Comment: but we applied for border using css mytable which not working.

Comment: check my answer below, I also rewrote your fiddle :)

Comment: oh great! please mark mine as the answer thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Rewrite this `.mytable td th` as `.mytable td, .mytable th`

Here: http://jsfiddle.net/y8B2j/1/

Comment: This works but there is duplicate entry .mytable td, .mytable td like this , If I remove one it is not working.Please help me to understand.

Comment: I don't know what the duplicate you are pointing, but that means applying the style on `.mytable` with child nodes `td` and `th`. Plus, `.mytable td` is different to `.mytable th`, would be better if you search the rulings on CSS.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
.mytable td, .mytable th
{
          border:1px solid green;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zbk6L/14/)

Answer (score 0):

I cant see any problem in above code, but you can try identifier instead of class by denoting it as '#mytable'.

Just give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

`th` selects every `<th>`-element.

`.mytable td th` selects all `<th>`-elements inside `<td>`-elements inside an element, that has class `mytable`.

I think what you need is this:

```
/* td & th elements inside 'mytable' */
.mytable td, .mytable th
{
  border:1px solid green;
}
/* th elements inside 'mytable' */
.mytable th
{
  background-color:green;
  color:white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Access like this:

`.mytable td`, `.mytable th` (It changes the property for all `td` and `th` nested inside the `.mytable`)

**OR**

If you have seperate class inside the mytable means

**HTML**

```
<div class="mytable">
    <div class="data">
        <ol>
           ...
        </ol>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.mytable.data ol //Accessing the child ol
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        <style>
        .mytable td th   
        {
                  border:1px solid green;
        }
        .mytable  th
        {
                  background-color:green;
                  color:white;
        }
        </style>



        <table class="mytable">
        <tr>
          <th>Firstname</th>
          <th>Lastname</th>
          <th>Savings</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Peter</td>
          <td>Griffin</td>
          <td>$100</td>
        </tr>
        </table>

        <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Firstname</th>
          <th>Lastname</th>
          <th>Savings</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Peter</td>
          <td>Griffin</td>
          <td>$100</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because, you write wrong CSS Rule :

Your css rule : `.mytable td th` refers to inner `th` tag into table columns `.mytable td`.

So, If you want apply your css style for both `th` and `td`. You need to write this one:

```
.mytable td, .mytable th 
{
   border:1px solid green;
}
```

[Try in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8td9n/2/)

Answer (score 0):

As i seen your code you using th as a child tag of td but th not child tag of td so use below code

[Click here for fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y8B2j/3/)

```
.mytable th
    {
       border:1px solid green;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add these lines on top of your Css file

```
tr{ background:#00CC66;}
th{ background:#ccCC66; border:1px dashed #0066FF;}
td{ background:#ffCC66;}
color:#fff;
```